# curl - download only exists multiple files from commandline

Tags: unix, command-line, curl

How download only exists files with curl via commandline? I have code like this:

```
curl http://host.com/photos/IMG_4[200-950].jpg -u user:pass -o IMG_4#1.jpg
```

This command download all images from IMG_4200.jpg to IMG_4950.jpg - even if they do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [-f](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-f)

> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at
>   all) on server errors. This is mostly
>   done to better enable scripts etc to
>   better deal with failed attempts. In
>   normal cases when a HTTP server fails
>   to deliver a document, it returns an
>   HTML document stating so (which often
>   also describes why and more). This
>   flag will prevent curl from outputting
>   that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there
>   are occasions where non-successful
>   response codes will slip through,
>   especially when authentication is
>   involved (response codes 401 and 407).